# Elasticsearch search in documents with certain values for a field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have an index with following document structure with 5 fields. I have written a  search query as follows :

```
{
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "field1.keyword",
            "field2.keyword",
            "field3.keyword"
          ],
          "query": "*abc*"
        }
      },
      "from": 0,
      "size": 1000
    }
```

This works fine but as a new requirement I have to search only in documents where field4 has a given set of values suppose (1,2,3) and omit rest of the documents. 
It is possible for me to obtain a list of field4 values which are to be omitted as they are present in the db with skip status.
Please suggest a solution for the same.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question bit more? What exactly is your document structure, mapping and what are you looking for?

Comment: @ibexit field1,field2,field3 are string and field 4 and field5 are numbers.documents are indexed on field5-field4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a filter query inside a bool query to match the docs that meet the condition.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "field1.keyword",
            "field2.keyword",
            "field3.keyword"
          ],
          "query": "*abc*"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "field4.keyword": [1, 2, 3]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked with some changes. filter clause inside the query .{
   "query":{
      "query_string":{
         "fields":[
            "path.keyword",
            "segmentId.keyword",
            "segmentName.keyword"
         ],
         "query":"*Vintage*"
      },
      "filter":{
         "term":{
            "datasetId":[
               912
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":1000,
   "sort":[

   ],
   "aggs":{

   }
}